Client DOM XSS vunerability
I have an LWC which i generating a url and loading an Iframe with generated url
JS Code:
this.generatedUrl = ${window.location.origin}/apex/vfPageName?templateId=${encodeURIComponent(this.templateId)}
HTML Code:  <iframe src={generatedUrl}></iframe>
This code is indicating a Client DOM XSS Vulnerability when I scanned the code.Could anyone suggest how can i resolve this Vulnerability.
